# How to persist the Z-order of my Window Forms app's windows?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, winapi

I have an app that opens at run-time 8 windows, each a graph.
How do I persist the Z-order of the 8 windows relative to each other?

My fellow employees use this app and stretch and move around the windows.
When they put one window over another, I want to restore this Z-order at boot.

Persisting location, dimensions (w & h), and `WindowState` works great.

I tried `GetChildIndex()` but at build-time I get:

> GetChildIndex() is not declared"

Answer (score 3):

A method that makes use of the [GetWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindow) function to determine the Z-Order of an application active (opened) Forms and then restore the same order when the application is restarted.

(For simplicity, the Forms' order is saved to a file in the application path. You need to adapt it to the application requirements (the current storage format))

When the application's Main Form is closing (`Form.FormClosing` event), the current Z-Order of the opened Forms is stored to a file.
**Note**: I'm supposing that the application Shutdown-mode is set to *When startup Form closes*.

The previous Z-Order of the Forms is restored when the Main Form is about to be shown (`Form.Shown` event). An instance of each of the Forms that were opened when the application was last closed is created and each Form is shown, preserving the Z-Order.

Each instance is created using the [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance) method, passing the Name of the Form retrieved from storage (a file, here).

**Note**: as of now, the Location of the Forms is not saved. You said you already have this working. The code presented here can be easily adapted to also store these measures, if required.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim zOrder As Dictionary(Of Integer, String) = GetWindowZOrder(Me.Handle, False)
    If zOrder Is Nothing Then return
    Using sw As New StreamWriter("FormsOrder.txt")
        For Each form In zOrder
            sw.WriteLine($"{form.Key},{form.Value}")
        Next
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    If File.Exists("FormsOrder.txt") Then
        Dim orderList As String() = File.ReadAllLines("FormsOrder.txt").Reverse().ToArray()
        Dim appNameSpace = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        For Each formOrder As String In orderList
            Dim formName As String = formOrder.Split(","c)(1)
            Dim form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType($"{appNameSpace}.{formName}")), Form)
            form.Show()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Declarations and `GetWindow` helper method (**`GetWindowZOrder`**):

The **`hwndFirst`** parameter of the `GetWindowZOrder` method is the handle of the Window from which the enumeration starts. It could be your Main Form (starting Form) or one of the Forms you open next.
If `hwndFirst` is your MainForm, you want to exclude it from the enumeration, passing `False` as the **`includeFirst`** parameter<sup>(1)</sup>. The opposite if `hwndFirst` is one of the *child* Forms.

<sub>(1) If this method is called from the Main Form, we don't want to open it again</sub>.

The `GetWindowZOrder` method then calls `GetWindow` to get the next Window handle in the current Z-Order, verifies that this handle belongs to the application and, if it is, adds it to a Dictionary.
It then returns a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)`, where the `Key` represents the order and the `Value` the name of the Form.

This code can be part of a Module.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Function GetWindowZOrder(hwndFirst As IntPtr, includeFirst As Boolean) As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    Dim zOrder As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)()
    Dim form As Form = GetOpenedForm(hwndFirst)
    If form Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    Dim order As Integer = 0
    If includeFirst Then zOrder.Add(order, form.Name)

    Dim hwndNext As IntPtr = hwndFirst
    While True
        hwndNext = GetWindow(hwndNext, GetWindowRel.GW_HWNDNEXT)
        If hwndNext = IntPtr.Zero Then Exit While
        form = GetOpenedForm(hwndNext)
        If (form IsNot Nothing) Then
            order += 1
            zOrder.Add(order, form.Name)
        End If
    End While
    Return zOrder
End Function

Private Function GetOpenedForm(hwnd As IntPtr) As Form
    Return Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form)().FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.Handle = hwnd)
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Function GetWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, uCmd As GetWindowRel) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Enum GetWindowRel As UInteger
    GW_HWNDFIRST = 0
    GW_HWNDLAST = 1
    GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
    GW_HWNDPREV = 3
    GW_OWNER = 4
    GW_CHILD = 5
    GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
End Enum
```