# Launch single form in tray application from desktop shortcut

Tags: vb.net

I'm rather new to VB and programming in general, and I could use a little guidance. I was able to build my application the way I want it but I just need one more piece... The desktop shortcut action.

Is there a way to launch a particular form in my project from a desktop shortcut?
There are 5 forms in the tray application, and I would like to be able to launch one in particular from a desktop shortcut. I have not been able to find anything relating to this; possibly due to incorrect phrasing and I'm guessing I need to use commandline args, but I'm not sure how to implement this into my project.

Here is the module code I have to this point.

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Module Module1
    Private MyNotifyIcon As NotifyIcon          'ICON IN SYSTEM TRAY COMPONENT
    Private MyContextMenu As ContextMenu        'CONTEXT MENU WHEN ITEM IS CLICKED ON
    Private WithEvents Tray As NotifyIcon

    Public Sub Main()

        Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath, RegistryValueKind.String)


        'CREATE INSTANCES OF OBJECTS WE NEED
        MyNotifyIcon = New NotifyIcon
        MyContextMenu = New ContextMenu

        MyNotifyIcon.Icon = My.Resources.co         'SET AN ICON (ICON IS A RESOURCE IN THE PROJECT)
        MyNotifyIcon.Visible = True                 'SET VISIBLE

        'ADD CAPTIONS AND EVENT HANDLERS FOR ITEMS IN CONTEXT MENU
        MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Support Ticket", AddressOf Ticket)
        MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Quick Self-Help", AddressOf SelfHelp)
        MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Instant Support", AddressOf Support)
        MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("System Information", AddressOf SysInfo)
        MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("-")
        MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("About", AddressOf About)
        'MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("-")
        'MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", AddressOf ExitApplication)
        If (Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift) Then
            MyContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("Tools", AddressOf Tools)
        End If

        MyNotifyIcon.ContextMenu = MyContextMenu        'ASSIGN CONTEXT MENU TO ICON

        Application.Run()

    End Sub

    'DELEGATE SUB TO EXIT APPLICATION
    Private Sub ExitApplication(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'CLEAN UP YOUR OBJECTS
        MyContextMenu.Dispose()
        MyNotifyIcon.Dispose()

        'EXIT APPLICATION LOOP
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    'SysInfo form
    Private Sub SysInfo(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim SysInfo As New formSysInfo
        SysInfo.Show()
    End Sub

    'Self Help form
    Private Sub SelfHelp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim Tools As New formTools
        formTools.Show()
    End Sub

    'Support form
    Private Sub Support(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Process.Start("https://weblink.com")
    End Sub

    'Ticket form
    Private Sub Ticket(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim Ticket As New formTicket
        formTicket.Show()
    End Sub

    'Double Click Action - Planned

    'About form
    Private Sub About(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim About As New formAbout
        formAbout.Show()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You need to build your application to accept commandline arguments that specify what form to start with. Handle the `Startup` event of the application and set the `MainForm` property based on the commandline argument(s). You don't need to write your own `Main` method.

Comment: ...or, you can change your Main in `Public Sub Main(args() As String)` and add e.g., `"SysInfo"` right after your executable's name in the Shortcut. When your app is run, `args(0)` will contain `"SysInfo"`. At this point, you can generate a new Form instance, using the code you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55804333/7444103) (first part, using `Application.CreateInstance`, setting `{formName}` to the `args(0)` string). After that, just `Application.Run(form)` instead of `form.Show()`. Of course you need to verify that the string you receive matches the name of one of your Forms.

Comment: Or use a *number* (or any other identifier) instead of a string and use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` to map the identifier to a Form name.

Comment: Jimi, I am pretty sure I get what you are saying but I'm just not sure of the syntax for this. (very noob. sorry.... )Based on the code you referenced, how would I reference the form I want to use without saving the form order in a text file, or can I somehow exclude that?